# Cannot autowire argument $tourist of "App\Controller\TouristController::edit()": it references class "App\Entity\Tourist" but no such service exists

Tags: php, symfony, crud

Изучаю Symfony 5. С помощью make:crud создал контроллер Tourist:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Tourist;
use App\Form\TouristType;
use App\Repository\TouristRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/tourist")
 */
class TouristController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="tourist_index", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(TouristRepository $touristRepository): Response
{
    return $this->render('tourist/index.html.twig', [
        'tourists' => $touristRepository->findAll(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/new", name="tourist_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $tourist = new Tourist();
    $form = $this->createForm(TouristType::class, $tourist);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($tourist);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('tourist_index');
    }

    return $this->render('tourist/new.html.twig', [
        'tourist' => $tourist,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="tourist_show", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function show(Tourist $tourist): Response
{
    return $this->render('tourist/show.html.twig', [
        'tourist' => $tourist,
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="tourist_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
 */
public function edit(Request $request, Tourist $tourist): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(TouristType::class, $tourist);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('tourist_index');
    }

    return $this->render('tourist/edit.html.twig', [
        'tourist' => $tourist,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="tourist_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
 */
public function delete(Request $request, Tourist $tourist): Response
{
    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$tourist->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($tourist);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('tourist_index');
}
}
```

Перейдя по ссылке /tourist/71/edit получаю ошибку:

> Cannot autowire argument $tourist of "App\Controller\TouristController::edit()": it references class "App\Entity\Tourist" but no such service exists.

Я могу исправить эту ошибку, изменив метод edit:

```
public function edit($id, Request $request, TouristRepository         $touristRepository): Response
{
$tourist = $touristRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
$form = $this->createForm(TouristType::class, $tourist);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('tourist_index');
}

return $this->render('tourist/edit.html.twig', [
    'tourist' => $tourist,
    'form' => $form->createView(),
]);
}
```

Вопрос: правильное ли это решение, и, если нет, то как правильно? И почему CRUD сгенерировался неправильно?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Круд в общем и целом сгенерен верно.

Предполагается что в случае с `edit` методом (как собственно и с другими) отрабатывает [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) который вам должен возвращать Tourist взятый по id, однако в силу того что с 3.4 версии Symfony `Container` инжектит в методы контроллера сервисы автоматически, очень вероятно что из за этого происходит странность. Вообще говоря в документации пишут о том что аннотацию `@ParamConverter` можно опускать при определенных условиях, но у вас по какой то  причине происходит попытка внедрить Tourist как сервис.

Попробуйте использовать `@ParamConverter` явным способом, как , например, указано в документации. Ну и проверьте что он у вас не отключен (хотя в других методах ведь работает).

Comment: Всё правильно, спасибо! У меня не был установлен https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html После его установки, симфони еще ругался на >An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("CSRF tokens can only be generated if a CsrfTokenManagerInterface is injected in FormRenderer::__construct().").   но если убрать во вью проверку на csrf, то метод работает правильно и страница открывается без ошибок!

Comment: CSRF ошибку я исправил с помощью composer require symfony/security-csrf